# A part of the foot armature of my model comes off whenever I move it

Tags: animation, armature, pose-mode

I've been working on a tutorial in Blender for low-poly character modeling, and when I try moving the model up, part of the left foot comes off. I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the tutorial I'm working on...
https://youtu.be/yjjLD3h3yRc?t=680

Here's a screenshot of the problem...

[image]

And here's the file of the project I'm working on right now...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a bone IK_Target.L that has no parent. (The same is true on the right.)  If you are moving the target bone, you can move it away from the rest of the foot.  That's how IK targets work.  But if you move the rest of the armature, the bone doesn't have a parent to follow, so it stays in place.

It is normal to add a *root* bone, and parent all of the loose bones like IK Targets and pole targets to the root.  Perhaps you've missed the part of the tutorial where that is done; or perhaps the tutorial just hasn't gotten to it yet.

You don't need to redo things at this point.  Simply add a bone at the origin, call it root and parent your IK_Target.L, IK_Target.R, and other loose bones to it.

Here is how to do this, step by step.

- Make sure you have the armature selected and are in *Edit* mode.
- You have moved the 3D cursor away from the origin.  To fix this, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Add a new bone by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>.
- Rotate the new bone so it will face forward by typing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Left click on your new bone to make sure it is the only selected bone
- Rename your new bone to root by typing <kbd>F2</kbd> and entering *root* in the selection box.

At this point you have your new root bone properly oriented:

[image: close up showing root bone]

- Deselect all bones by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>
- Select the bone `IK_Target.R` by left clicking on it
- Select the bone `IK_Target.L` by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while left clicking on it.
- Select the bone `Pelvis_bone` by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while left clicking on it.
- Select the bone `root` by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while left clicking on it.

At this point your display will look like this

[image: armature showing selected bones]

- Parent all of the selected bones to the root bone by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>‐<kbd>P</kbd> and selecting *Keep Offset*

[image: Selecting keep offset]

and then [Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer and don't expect the volunteers who answer questions here to do this much work for you when you're not willing to scan back through a tutorial and find the bits you missed.

Comment: I did see something about bone parenting in the last tutorial, but I don't want to have to redo everything. That's frustrating to me.

Comment: you don't necessarily need to redo everything, just create a root bone and parent the target bones and the pole target bones to this root

Comment: Would creating a root bone cause problems for my model's armature? Where would I have to put it?

Comment: See the paragraph I just added.

Comment: I'm a visual hands-on learner, so a picture would help me.

Comment: There's already a visual in the tutorial, I'm sure.

Comment: Can you find the part, I don't want to start over on my character project just to do that. Showing where to place a bone on an origin and making it the root bone is something I still need help with.

Comment: Does this look better? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BxPpQMbg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BxPpQMbg/) I created a new bone, but I don't know how to pair the smaller bones to it without causing problems for my model.

Comment: I can't name a bone by pressing F2. What do I do?

Comment: I did what was shown, but does that bone detach from the rest when you move it not something to worry about?

Comment: Is the bone detaching at a certain angle something to worry about? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vvrkYSpn" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vvrkYSpn/)

Comment: If you select the bone, you can always go the bone properties in the properties editor and change the name there.  The target bone will detach.  It's something to worry about when you're animating because it means you've pulled the target to far for the skeleton, but it's proper behavior.

Comment: Does that typically happen?

Comment: I don't know about typically, but at least one walk cycle tutorial teaches how to position the legs by pulling the IK target until it starts to separate and then backing off a little bit, so a lot of people have seen it happen.

Comment: Is it bad if the foot of the model goes past the Y-Line? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=B0oK7xpd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/B0oK7xpd/)